# Mysql on C# is not opening "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open.'"

Tags: c#, mysql

/*I just want to access my database(mysql) on Visual Studio2017(C#) The message always shows  "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Connection must be valid and open.'" */

```
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection
            ("server = 127.0.0.1; user id = root; database = music_db;SSL mode = none;");
            connection.Open();
            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand();
            comm.CommandText = "SELECT * From songs";
            comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            MySqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();

            string str = "[year]\t[composed]\t[title]\t[album_from]\t[gendreID]";


            if (rd.HasRows)
            {
                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    str += Convert.ToString(rd.GetInt32(0)) + "\t" + rd.GetString(1) + "\t" + rd.GetString(2) + "\t"
                        + rd.GetString(3) + "\t" + rd.GetInt32(4)+Environment.NewLine;
                }
                rd.Close();
            }





            Console.WriteLine(str);

            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("CloseD");
        }
        catch (MySqlException err)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(err);
            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: I gave the solution fo sql not mysql. But same Mistake:

```
// Replace
MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand();

// with
MySqlCommand comm = connection.CreateCommand();
```

Old Answer:

You open the connection, but you don't give your command a reference to that open connection

Please use using when working with sql-connection, to make sure that the connection will always be closed.

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
string connectionString)
{
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
   {
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
      command.Connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

You can use this ctor for your command

```
public SqlCommand (string cmdText, SqlConnection connection);
```